# how to add ArrayList data to the same # in derby?

Tags: java, database, derby

so i have this issue not sure how to solve it i want to add arraylist data  such as [A,b,c,d,e,f] to the first record looking something like this

```
"#"|| ID  ||  numbers  || section

`1 ||  1  ||  Abcdef  ||   A1
```

here is my code

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
String sql = "INSERT INTO LOCATION (ID,LETTERS,SECTION) "
        + "VALUES (?,?,?)";
System.out.println(ch.size());
try (PreparedStatement insert = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        insert.setString(1, "1");
        insert.setString(3, "A1");
    for (int i = 0; i < ch.size(); i++) { 
         insert.setString(2, ch.get(i).toString());
         insert.executeUpdate();
    }
    st.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two problems

- Your code executes an update (`insert.executeUpdate()`) so many times as your `ch` arraylist size
- You are invoking the setString as many times as the length of your arraylist but passing it a single character and not a concatenation of the elements of your arraylist

That part of your code should be:

```
   String arrayChars = "";
   for (int i = 0; i < ch.size(); i++) { 
         arrayChars += ch.get(i).toString(); // If youre using an array of strings theres no need to use .toString()
    }
    insert.setString(2, arrayChars);
    insert.executeUpdate();
```